# Consulta en SQL, Suma de campos de una misma columna

Tags: sql-server, sql

Buen día a todos,

Tengo esta tabla con los siguientes datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver para la Planta 1 le corresponde la Bocatoma 1 y 2, y a la Planta 2 le corresponde la Bocatoma 3 y 4, soy nueva en esto de sql y me gustaría sacar la suma del valor de las bocatomas para la planta 1 y 2.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Como se llama tu tabla ?

Comment: La tabla se llama fact_caudal_bocatoma

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Si no indicas datos como el nombre de la tabla y las consultas que ya has intentado, junto con los errores o problemas encontrados, es una pregunta de baja calidad. Poner a transcribir datos y definiciones de tablas desde imágenes se lo hace más difícil a los que quieran ayudar (es igual que responderte con código puesto en una imagen...). De paso, no sabemos el tipo de dato de las columnas, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola amigo desconociendo el nombre de tu tabla solo le pondre tabla, ya tu le pondrias el nombre de tu tabla,

Al realizar una suma en SQL Server, los campos que traigas debes de incluirlo en el GROUP BY

asi como se ve aqui

```
SELECT Fecha,Periodo,Planta,SUM(Valor) AS Valor
FROM 
fact_caudal_bocatoma 
WHERE Planta IN(1,2)
GROUP BY  Fecha,Periodo,Planta
```

Comment: Muchas gracias era lo que necesitaba, perdón por la poca información en la pregunta

Comment: Si esto responde tu pregunta, no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta, Saludos :D